# ld: unknown option: -T on MacOS

Tags: linker, ld

I compile a simple boot code on MacOS,But got a ld error :

```
#ld -Tlink.ld -o kernel.bin start.o main.o scrn.o    
ld: unknown option: -Tlink.ld
#ld -T
ld: unknown option: -T
```

ld version is :

```
$ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-650.9
BUILD 13:09:02 May 28 2021
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 12.0.5, (clang-1205.0.22.11) (static support for 27, runtime is 27)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 12.0.5 (tapi-1205.0.7.1)
```

I search internet for a while,But no found any useful solution.
How can i link this script successful? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I compile a simple boot code on MacOS,But got a ld error :

It looks like you are trying to build a boot loader which assumes GNU tools with native MacOS tools.

You'll need to use *appropriate* tools instead.